# Como executar programas sem caminho especifico

Tags: c#, .net, path, io

**Exemplo:**
Quero que automaticamente faça uma busca do programa que eu escrever, e se achar uma aplicação ".exe" ele execute-o, caso não encontre, mande uma mensagem dizendo que o programa não esta instalado no computador.

```
Process.Start(Programa + ".exe");
```

Queria saber se tem como, pois procurei bastante e não achei.

Comment: Ha... em C#  ou C sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você está tentando executar um aplicativo cujo local não está determinado, tente procurar ele recursivamente usando um diretório raiz.

Assim, o método `GetFiles` irá enumerar todos os arquivos executáveis recursivamente em todas as pastas do diretório `root`:

Referências:

```
using System.IO;
```

Código:

```
string ProcurarOArquivo(string nome, string root) {
     // nome  -> nome do arquivo que esta sendo procurado
     // root  -> pasta raiz
     string[] Arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
     foreach(string a in Arquivos) {
          string A = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(a);
          if(A.ToLower() == nome.ToLower()) return a;
          // A    -> arquivo com nome cortado
          // a    -> arquivo com nome e caminho completo
     }
     return "";
}
```

E para usar, chame o método `ProcurarOArquivo()` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
// no exemplo abaixo, PastaParaProcurar é o diretório onde
// o aplicativo está sendo executado. Você pode alterar por
// qualquer diretório literal ou variável.
string PastaParaProcurar = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
// enfim chama o arquivo executável.
Process.Start(ProcurarOArquivo(Programa, PastaParaProcurar));
```

---

> **Observações:**
>
> - Se o arquivo não for encontrado, irá ser retornado uma `String` vazia.
> - Se quiser procurar pelo sistema inteiro, coloque `"C:\"` em `PastaParaProcurar`, mas o uso de processador e memória será arbitrariamente grande.